# How can I increase the line length in Atom with prettier-atom?

Tags: atom-editor, prettier

When my lines run a bit too long, saving the file auto-formats the code into multiple lines. I've spent more than I care to admit figuring out how to increase the line length to avoid multiple lines yet nothing seems to work. It seems like Atom doesn't want to pick up any of my config files. I have a `~./prettierrc` file that's not recognized. And is `printWidth` the right option to use?

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart Atom for the changes to take effect. https://github.com/prettier/prettier-atom/issues/489